# Integrate google doc form with paypal

Tags: forms, paypal, google-docs

I'm looking for a way to have a form which submits to a google doc, which also allows customers to pay via paypal.

I prefer google docs for the main form submissions since the list of purchases needs to be reviewed by a very non-technical group.

But there does not seem to be a way for me to integrate a paypal button into these forms. I currently have it as two separate forms but this is horribly user-unfriendly.

Any suggestions? I am open to other payment processors which might work with google docs, but do not want to use google wallet. Needs to be open to anyone, even without google accounts.

Comment: Same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136328/paypal-custom-link-to-payment

Comment: @Robert not exactly - I want the paypal submission to be integrated with the application form. So one single form which both submits to a googledoc and also submits the credit card info to paypal for authorization/capture.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a site to solve the problem for myself:
[http://www.crazychro.me/gform](http://www.crazychro.me/gform/)