# Paypal custom link to payment

Tags: html, paypal

I am new to Paypal and have previously build an invoicing application for the company I work for and wish to send a link on the invoice where they can pay their bill, how would I go about doing this? I have sifted through Paypal and questions on Stackoverflow but perhaps I am missing something!
Even if I can't generate a link perhaps there is a way I can link them to a Paypal/custom form where they can pay?

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=the-recipient@email.here&amount=0.99&item_name=99%20problems%20but%20this%20invoice%ain't%20one

Additional parameters you can specify in the GET are listed on https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics

**Note:** The amount would be plainly visible in the link. If you want to make it that little bit more secure, I would highly recommend looking into the [BMCreateButton](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_BMCreateButton) API call.