# Google Forms Launch Paypal on Submit

Tags: paypal, google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to use the URL method of launching a Paypal purchase flow described in [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136328/paypal-custom-link-to-payment)

Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to launch a new website on the submission of a form.  I've created a function and linked it to the onSubmit through the project triggers button but that's where I've stalled.  I can't seem to find any other information on it.  Am I going about this the wrong way or is there something else I should be looking at?

```
function launchPayPal() {
     //launch website here?
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google Forms do not allow you to redirect to another web page on form submissions. You can however add a PayPal link in the message that shows up on the screen when a form is submitted.

Comment: FWIW I set this up recently and wrote a longer answer about how I did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067157/230779

Answer (score 2):

You need a website, or a Google Apps Script Stand Alone App.  Instead of triggering a Google Form to open from your spreadsheet, have a link to a Google Site, or a link to a Google Apps Script Stand Alone App.  Or you could have a Dialog Box or Sidebar with HTML in it that opens up.  That way, the HTML Dialog Box or the Sidebar could open up Pay Pal.  So, you need to create something with HTML rather than use a Google Form.  So, your options are:

- Google Site with HTML in it.
- Dialog Box with HTML
- Sidebar with HTML
- Apps Script HTML Service Stand Alone App